# How to share a ppp internet connection over wlan interface on ubuntu?

Tags: internet, ppp, wlan

Im using a 3G USB huawei modem to get access to the internet, therefore, i have an active **ppp** interface addressed.
I want to share this access with my **wlan** interface so that every device that will get connected to my wifi hotspot will get access to the internet too.
How can i do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ubuntu 14 or ubuntu 15, you can use this command : 
- first, you activate routing :

```
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

- second, you write a dynamic translation rule source IP address.

```
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -s address/mask -o internet_interface -j MASQUERADE
```

where **adress/mask** is a address range who don't have the internet access, and then **internet_interface** is the interface who have the internet access.
Example of this rule :

```
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -s 192.168.7.0/24 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```